2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Bitcoin breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1         46
Users destroyed                                 182          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           310        947
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               29        106
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        114        779
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              136        862
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               527      3,826
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              677      2,570
Tags merged                                      32          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            21          0
Tag synonyms created                             22          0
Questions reopened                               20          0
Questions protected                               1        165
Questions migrated                               21          0
Questions merged                                  6          0
Questions flagged⁴                               18      2,015
Questions closed                              1,080        509
Question flags handled⁴                         809      1,224
Posts unlocked                                    0          4
Posts undeleted                                  40         65
Posts locked                                      5        421
Posts deleted⁵                                1,646      3,325
Posts bumped                                      0      8,647
Comments undeleted                                9          0
Comments flagged                                  1        697
Comments deleted⁶                               269      1,242
Comment flags handled                           210        488
Answers flagged                                  42      4,036
Answer flags handled                          2,838      1,240
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Bitcoin without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...
